# How to convert this NSData to NSString?

Tags: objective-c

I have NSData like this:

```
455a4f4e 00000001 01020304 00000000 00000000
```

My code:

```
Byte bytes[] = {0x45, 0x5a, 0x4f, 0x4e, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", str); // prints "EZON"
```

I wish the result to be `EZON0001` etc...

Why does the print result not include the digits following 'EZON'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the zero after 0x4e is not the ASCII/UTF-8 digit '0' but the end of string marker. it should be 0x30, not 0x00...

Comment: Make sure you do leave one 0 at the end of the byte array for the null terminator.

Comment: @rmaddy: That is not necessary. `dataWithBytes:length:` does not require the bytes to be 0-terminated, and `initWithData:encoding:` does not require the data to be 0-terminated.

Comment: @MartinR I knew the NSData didn't need to be null terminated but I mistakenly thought the string would need to be. But it makes sense that NSString is smart enough in this regard. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    Byte bytes[] = {0x45, 0x5a, 0x4f, 0x4e, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];
    NSString* newStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
    NSLog(@"%@", newStr);
```

Comment: The problem is that the wrong bytes for the characters `0 0 0 1` etc. are supplied. The rest of the code is fine.

Comment: @ravindhiran: No need to answer, when you see an answer having 4 upvotes, unless you see you can give better.